# How to I make python print out the users response?

Tags: python

So, my python code asks a question, and I want it to repeat the user's answer.

Example:

```
FC = input('What's your favorite colour?')
print(' Oh so you like (users answer)!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicly:

```
FC = input("What's your favorite colour?")
print(f' Oh so you like {FC}!')
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer f-strings:

```
FC = input('What's your favorite colour?')
print(f'Oh so you like {FC}!')
```

Also you can use other ways to format a string:

```
...
print('Oh so you like {}!'.format(FC))
...
print('Oh so you like {user_answer}!'.format(user_answer=FC))
...
print('Oh so you like %s!' % FC)
```